# Fresh Installation, with all old data. Current online version CiviCRM 4.6.20. (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, data-import

I am very glad with the nice CiviCRM! This is an perfect online CRM-system!

After a lot years now, i would like to upgrade to the current version. But i am very scared if it would work.. The Current version: CiviCRM 4.6.20. is upgraded from an earlier version, and that was also with a lot of errors..

Does someone know how to do this the best way. There is very much information in the system, if there is something going wrong, it is a very big problem...

What is the best way to install a new version, and get all the data from the old.

Thanks a lot.

With Kind Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

We have nursed about 50 sites through such an upgrade, many of which we inherited rather than built

Firstly read the docs: docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade

1. minimise risk by doing the upgrade on a copy of the site - that way you will be able to identify the problems and come back for more specific advice once you know what issues you have hit.
2. identify any customised files you have on your system and assume they will break - and consider if there are better ways to manage those customisations such as in Extensions
3. if you have budget consider getting a Partner who can step in to do this or at least be available on an 'as required basis' to help mentor, provide emergency support etc.

Comment: And also read the docs: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/

Answer (score 1):

When I've had a site like that where there were errors with past upgrades, I start with a blank slate and recreate everything. This ensures that your databases are built correctly, have the right tables, etc. But make sure you do it with a COPY of your site and not the live one.

In the past I've used this link as a model, but I haven't been able to find a version for 4.7.x:

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC42/Ensuring+Schema+Integrity+on+Upgrades

It gives you a good idea of how to reload everything so that your database should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can also likely get support while doing it on chat.civicrm.org

Comment: probably better as a comment? looks like user4278 is making good input - hence trying to help you finesse your SE usage